# How to control row height in lightning:layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, slds, slds-grid

I have a lightning:layout with a lightning:layoutItem, containing a lightning:select.

I want the row in the layout to be only the height of the select box but I can't figure out how to remove the space above it.

Here is my component:

```
    <div class="slds-is-relative">
    <lightning:layout verticalAlign="start">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small" size="1">
            <lightning:select
                aura:id="select"
                name="regionFilter"
                value="{!v.filterSelectedValueRegion}"
                onchange="{!c.applyRegionFilter}"
                class="slds-m-bottom_medium"
                >
                <option value="Default">-- Region --</option>
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <aura:iteration var="filterRegionOption" items="{!v.filterOptionsRegion}">
                    <option
                        value="{!filterRegionOption}"
                        text="{!filterRegionOption}"
                        selected="{!filterRegionOption.selected}"
                        />
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
```

This is how it renders:

[image: screenshot 1]

I want to reduce the vertical space between 'Home' and region selector.

This is what the inspector shows:

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

How do I get rid of that space above and below the region select box?

Answer (score 1):

Further to comment from @sfdcfox above I tested some variations.  This is the component:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="Option1" type="String" default="Option 1"/>

<div class="slds-is-relative">
<lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="My Button 1"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="My Button 2"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
        <lightning:select
            aura:id="select1"
            name="regionFilter1"
            label="A"
            variant="label-hidden"
        >
            <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        </lightning:select>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
        <lightning:select
            aura:id="select2"
            name="regionFilter2"
            label="A"
            variant="label-inline"
        >
            <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        </lightning:select>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
        <select id="sel">
            <option value="{!v.Option1}">{!v.Option1}</option>
            <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
</div>
```

and this is the result:

[image: screenshot]

Interestingly, the `variant="label-inline"` on 'select2' seems to have no effect, but the lightning:select docs state 'Use label-inline to horizontally align the label and input field.'

Answer (score 0):

Some padding is inevitable, because of the nature of form elements in SLDS, but you can reduce the space by hiding the label:

```
<lightning:select variant="label-hidden" ...
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it didn't change the display, with or without also adding a label="..." attribute :-(

Comment: @MikeA The only other option would be to use a normal `<select>` element instead of the lightning:select.

Comment: That is the answer @sfdcfox, "use a normal <select> element instead of the lightning:select"